# Ego sum Sol - I am the sun

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I’m wondering if someone could help me with the Latin translation:

I am the sun - Ego sum Sol

Is it correct? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Any special meanings you want to convey with this? Does "sun" here mean the literal sun, or is it more metaphorical?

Comment: @Adam Thank you for welcoming me. Well it supposed to mean something like I’m the center of my world and I’m shining.

Answer (score 4):

Capitalization aside, this is fine as is. Strictly speaking, [you don't need the pronoun here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/i-make-create-therefore-i-am) in phrases like these, though you do see it in biblical Latin, because it's translating the Greek (which in turn could be translating an Aramaic substrate). So you'll see *ego sum via et veritas*, "I am the way and the truth."

You also see it used for emphasis or clarification. So if you say *ego sum sol*, it would sound like you're saying, "*I* (and not anyone else) am the sun."

Given the context ("in your world"), I'd say this is fine.

You could also comfortably cut the *ego* and even reverse the order of the words, if you like, and it would still make sense.